# Validation between start date and end date php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to validate input date fields, and I want to make sure that the entires are no more than 90 days difference from each other. 
Could anyone offer any solutions to the function I need to be using here.
Below is my psuedocode of what I want to achieve.

```
if (($filter_in['dt']-90) > ($filter_in['df']));
```

The `-90` bit is where I need to minus 90 days from the end date. Is it possible to go about this in this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-09-13');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
$diff= $interval->format('%R%a');
if($diff=="+90"){
   //your code
}
?>
```

or in above code you can just format like this

```
$diff= $interval->format('%a');
```

or simply like @vascowhite said

```
$diff= $interval->days;
```

to get a positive integer only, the above code returns `28` which is in days.

Comment: Or use $diff = $interval->days to get an integer to compare 90 to. However, +1 for using DateTime.

Comment: Nice! That won't execute "your code" if $diff is > "+90" though, only if it is exactly +90(?).  (http://codepad.viper-7.com/ia4A6y)

Comment: @TerrySeidler, he just wants to check if the difference between two date is 90, i have edited the solution.

Comment: I read "no more than 90 days" differently, but I approve of the edit ;)

Comment: No, he wants to check if it is less than 90.

Comment: if he gets 90 as the result, its enough to check more or less than the 90 days, I guess :)